# Launching app on iOS 5 with Social framework causes crash

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, frameworks, social-framework

I haven't used Social framework in my code at all yet, I've only imported it into the project. This causes it to crash on iOS 5, because Social framework isn't supported yet for that. How can I import it in a way that my iOS 5 users can still launch the app without having it?

Comment: just set it as optional in build phases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set it as optional in Build phases. See below image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Just set optional to social.framework instead of MessageUI.framework in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the SocialFramework as a optional.

Hope this help!!